# Detecting characters in C++ char stream

Tags: c++, string, stream, char

I am working on a piece of arduino code that is using the BlackWidow version with wifi built in. Using the WiServer.h library,  I'm using the SimpleClient.pde example with mods to send a call to a webserver that will simply return an integer - 0, 1, or 2. The end goal is to turn on a pin for the proper red, green, or yellow of a stoplight. The integers represent the aggregate state of our Hudson CI.

I'm a PHP lazy bastard, and pointers scare me. The code I am working with is

```
// Function that prints data from the server
void printData(char* data, int len) {

  // Print the data returned by the server
  // Note that the data is not null-terminated, may be broken up into smaller packets, and 
  // includes the HTTP header. 
  while (len-- > 0) {
    Serial.print(*(data++));
  }
}
```

printData() is the callback of the call to the webserver, and when run it sends the following to the serial monitor (this is 3 loops, no newline before new output):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2011 17:37:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2 PHP/5.2.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2011 17:37:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2 PHP/5.2.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2011 17:37:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2 PHP/5.2.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

0
```

The part that I need to identify is the 0, which could also be 1 or 2.

Instead of printData(), this function will become turnOnAppropriateLight() or something, by simply setting a pin to HIGH. This will then activate a relay, to power the corresponding LED array.

Now that I've written this up it looks like I just need to keep the last character around and do a switch based on the value. The *(data++) is the confusing part even though I know it's incrementing a pointer index...I'm just not sure how to go directly to the last char in that index. No need for this looping to spit out the result.

[image: arduino and 4-relay board]
[image]

Comment: Do you need to know when characters are available in the stream or do you need to *parse* the characters in the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not robust AT ALL, but

```
Serial.print(data[len-1])
```

See what that gets you

Comment: SimpleClientLights.cpp: In function 'void printData(char*, int)':
SimpleClientLights:69: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'

Comment: Weird - the printData func is called twice for each GET request some reason. Some sort of WiServer thing...

Answer (score 1):

this should be all you need:

```
data[len - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be neurotic and parse each line, or look for the last tags: *Content-Type*:.

I would convert the C-style string into a C++ `std::string` then use the `find_first` method to look for the keywords.

The `std::istringstream` can be used to convert from text "0" to numeric 0.